# Securing (AuthN/AuthZ) an app running on Kubernetes in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have an application with a front-end (Angular) and back-end (Spring Boot) running in a Kubernetes cluster, in two pods, behind the same ingress controller, on Azure Kubernetes.

I am looking for a way to secure the access to back and front-ends from outside Azure:

- Front-end client should be accessed by authorized users only
- Back-end should be reachable as an API by authorized services through http calls

My problem is, I feel like the way the app is deployed is not really common. There is documentation on how to deal with access to apps deployed on App service for example, and about how to grant accesses to kubernetes clusters and pods for admin purpose, but I can't find doc applying to what I'm trying to achieve. The way it's deployed cannot be changed.

I am wondering if there's even a solution using Azure tools, or if the only way is low level, programatical?

Comment: Answer: Azure AD. this should get you started https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide

Comment: and for angular https://medium.com/medialesson/authenticating-angular-apps-with-azure-active-directory-using-msal-angular-1-0-d7b2f4914be9

Comment: keycloak is good way to implement however that will be more integration and work to do. adding a comment for reference only people also use it with kong.

Comment: @silent I understood from the doc that Azure AD fits perfectly for authenticating to App Services e.g. (because the app has to be registered in the AD service) but it doesn't seem to work when the app is served from a container. Or have you done it and I got it wrong?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly fine as well from basically any app platform. I'm not into java but this looks like a good example. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in